How to set encoding for headers in Springdoc
I have a problem with the Swagger documentation auto-generated by Swagger. The issue is that despite me having set my project to UTF-8, the authentication headers are still encoded in ISO-8859-1, which causes problems with special characters in passwords. I have already tried a number of things, but could not figure anything that works.
Here's what the relevant part of my application.yml looks like:
server:
  servlet:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      enabled: true
      force: true

The endpoint in question looks like this:
    @PostMapping(value = Endpoints.USER_CHECK,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Operation(
        security = @SecurityRequirement(name = AuthGroups.BASIC_AUTH))
    )
    public UserCheckResponse postUserCheck(
        @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails
    ) {
        if (userDetails == null) {
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,"Login failed: Credentials not set");
        }
        return portalService.postUserCheck(userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword());
    }

...with the security scheme being defined as:
@SecurityScheme(
    name = AuthGroups.BASIC_AUTH,
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
    scheme = "basic"
)

Now, I have confirmed that if I call the endpoint via Postman, it works just fine, but when I do the same request using the auto-generated Swagger documentation, then the authorization header is suddenly encoded in ISO-8859-1:



Client
Input Authentication
Generated Auth Header




Postman
Test:Müll
Authorization: Basic VGVzdDpNw7xsbA==


Springdoc Swagger
Test:Müll
Authorization: Basic VGVzdDpN/Gxs



What do I need to do in order to get the Springdoc Swagger page to encode the authorization header in UTF-8?

UPDATE:
I also checked the generated swagger page, and its charset is set to UTF-8, which makes me even more confused about why the header is encoded in ISO-8859-1:
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


Okay, so while I did not find a way to set the header encoding in the auto-generated Swagger documentation page, I did find a workaround by creating custom filters that are able to decode both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 headers correctly. The whole workaround looks like this:
MyUserDetails
import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public MyUserDetails (String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of();
    }
}

MyAuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.authentication.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class MyAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(
        Authentication authentication
    ) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
        UserDetails user = new MyUserDetails(username, password);
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(
            user,
            password,
            authentication.getAuthorities()
        );
    }
}

MyAuthenticationFilter
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class MyAuthenticationFilter extends
    AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    MyAuthenticationFilter(){
        setAuthenticationManager(new MyAuthenticationManager());
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            String decodedHeader = decodeBasicAuthHeader(header);
            String[] values = decodedHeader.split(":", 2);
            return values[0];
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            String decodedHeader = decodeBasicAuthHeader(header);
            String[] values = decodedHeader.split(":", 2);
            return values[1];
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String decodeBasicAuthHeader(String header) {
        String basicAuthHeader = header.substring("Basic".length()).trim();
        byte[] credDecoded = Base64.getDecoder()
            .decode(basicAuthHeader);
        try {
            return decode(credDecoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
            try {
                return decode(credDecoded, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
            } catch (CharacterCodingException ex) {
                throw new NotImplementedException(
                    "Basic auth header is not encoded in a supported charset"
                        + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "Supported Charsets are: UTF-8, ISO_8859_1");
            }
        }
    }

    private static String decode(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
        throws CharacterCodingException {
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
        decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        CharBuffer charBuffer = decoder.decode(byteBuffer);
        return charBuffer.toString();
    }
}

AuthConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class AuthConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new MyAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}

While this works, it strikes me as overly complicated. If someone knows a better solution, please do share it!
